# "A killed person" VS "A person killed"

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar, adjectives, grammaticality-in-context

> - a killed person. I saw a killed person in the street.
> - a person killed. I saw a person killed in the street.
>
> Is there any difference in meaning between two these phrases, and are they both acceptable and interchangeably used in context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two usages are not interchangeable, but both are acceptable—provided we supply the singular, uncountable noun *street* with a *determiner*!

The difference between the two sentences is a very simple one. In your first sentence, the *past participle* **killed** is in the *prenominal* position (before the noun). This causes it to be interpreted as an *adjectival* form that modifies the noun *person*:

> I saw a killed person in the street.

This tells us that you saw a person in the street who had been killed.

In your second sentence, the *past participle* is in the *postnominal* position (after the noun), and this causes **killed** to be interpreted as a passive *verb* form with the noun as its patient:

> I saw a person *[being]* killed in the street.

This tells us that you saw the killing as it was taking place.

In English, past participles frequently serve as adjectives. However, the past participle of *kill* is seldom used in this way. If we substitute a verb whose participle is more commonly used in this way, the sentences are much more idiomatic:

> I saw a *frightened* person in the street.
>   I saw a person *frightened* in the street.
>
> I saw a *tattooed* person in the street.
>   I saw a person *tattooed* in the street.

Comment: Thank you for this perfect answer. But a person, isn't the subject or object because the word person is receiving the action of killing as an object. "and this causes killed to be interpreted as a verb form with the noun as its ***subject***? :

Comment: I'm not sure that killed person is even really right here. Kill is an action verb, as it were. Let's take another: I saw a beaten person in  the street. Most unusual. Anyway, killed is merely an adjective. I saw a dead person in the street, more like it.

Comment: @Lambie You're absolutely right, this _killed_ is out of band. I've only seen _killed_ as an adjectival in medical writing (_killed vaccine, killed virus_) but in this business we play the cards we're dealt.

Comment: @BavyanYaldo To address your comment and for clarity, I edited the answer. Good catch!

Comment: @P.E. Dant A "killed" person is a dead person. Where "dead" functions like frightened, alarmed or any other state-of-mind verb. Funny thing, that, huh? Dead as state of mind.

Answer (score 0):

The first one clearly suggests that the person you saw was the one that was killed and makes good sense for your listeners.

The second sentence, on the other hand, does not make sense the way you have written it.

The verb pattern is "to see somebody **DOING** something". That inquires the sentence to be:

**I saw a person *killing* in the street.** ---> In this case, the person, who you saw, was the one *doing the killing*.

Another verb pattern is "to see somebody **DO** something"

**I saw a person *kill* in the street.** ---> In this case, you've been watching this person killing in the street from the beginning until the end.

You can either put an infinitive without "to" or a gerund, but a past simple form of the verb has no use in this sentence whatsoever.

Comment: Look at this extracted text from a game of thrones: They set forth at daybreak to see a man beheaded, twenty in all, and Bran . Pay attention to the ***see*** a man ***beheaded***. Beheaded here is p.p, so this phrase is similar to the second sentence in my question; I saw a person killed by someone in street.

Comment: Personally, I think this sentence is either colloquial or wrong. I would phrase it as "to see a man being beheaded". But, hey, I'm not George R.R. Martin, and thank gods I'm not in Game of Thrones!

Comment: Hahahaha. Maybe you are true because a linguistic person told me that a writer can took some liberty in his writing and typography. So he could use his words in the way he wants, and ignore some grammar. We could name it a creative writing. @Martin

Answer (score -1):

Yes, a huge difference. 
"A killed person" suggests a person that has been killed, whereas "A person killed" means a person that has killed.

Perhaps you meant "A person, killed" which with the comma would suggest the former - "A killed person"

Comment: You are correct about the first one, but you are wrong about the second. Because a person killed, is kind of passive; a person killed by someone: a person is receiving the process of killing

Comment: Yes i think second one is incomplete it requires by someone to complete it